# Customize Quick Look to allow me to view .yml files

Tags: finder, preview, quicklook, text

I would like to use "space" to preview *.yml files directly out of the finder on Mac OS X.

I think I have to tell finder to launch the text file quick view handler for files with that type and this has something to do with universal type identifiers (UTI.)

But that's as far as I was able to get.

Can anyone give me the magic formula? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Ciarán Walsh’s TextMate in QuickLook](http://ciaranwal.sh/2007/11/15/quicklook-and-textmate) plugin.

> This is a TextMate plug-in and a QuickLook generator which renders QuickLook previews (for certain filetypes) using the TextMate syntax highlighter. Currently it’s configured to highlight Perl, PHP, Ruby, Shell, C headers and Obj-C(++). Note: this effectively sets up TextMate as a server for the syntax highlighting, so it won’t work unless TM is running (QuickLook will just fall back to the standard preview if it’s not).

Here is a [convenience](http://ciaranwal.sh/files/QuicklookTM.tmplugin.zip) link to download the plugin and you can read more about it on Ciarán's web page.

This is what it looks like when I QuickLook a .yml file:

[image: .yml QuickLook]

Comment: This accepted answer > 10 years old. See my answer for a more modern solution.

Answer (score 12):

I've had great luck with the free QLStephen plugin for Quick Look. It displays lots of other plaintext formats.
To preview `YAML` files with this plugin [these additional steps need to be followed](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/390937/24324) after plugin installation.

You can get it [here](https://github.com/whomwah/qlstephen).

Comment: This should be the selected answer. Also, for installation instructions: https://github.com/whomwah/qlstephen

Comment: Worked again in 2018! Cool feature

Comment: Did not work in 2020. Do I have to put a special setting?

Comment: Yes, read the github page where installation is explained. On Catalina the com.apple.quarantine extended attribute must be removed.

Comment: Works for me in 2021, but crucially you have to add `public.yml` to `LSItemContentTypes` in `~/Library/QuickLook/QLStephen.qlgenerator/Contents/Info.plist` as described in another answer on this page

Answer (score 12):

You can use the QLStephen plugin as mentioned but you will need to edit it as described in the project's issue tracker: https://github.com/whomwah/qlstephen/issues/23#issuecomment-21769063

Basically:

1. Open the `~/Library/QuickLook/QLStephen.qlgenerator/Contents/Info.plist` file in a text editor
2. Add the UTI `public.yaml` to the key `LSItemContentTypes`
3. Run `qlmanage -r` to reload the service

Comment: I also had to restart the finder. Then Big Sur complained that `QLStephen.qlgenerator` is broken, so I tried `xattr -cr ~/Library/QuickLook/QLStephen.qlgenerator` (from https://github.com/whomwah/qlstephen/issues/81#issuecomment-574148579) to clear the quarantine extended attribute.

Answer (score 8):

Most of these didn't work for me.

This did: https://github.com/sbarex/SourceCodeSyntaxHighlight

Really excellent, worked immediately, lots of options.

Comment: Great little plugin!

Comment: This is a beautiful option, offering quick look WITH syntax highlighting!